# What are the pros and cons of ros2 node configuration and controller configuration?

Tags: ros2, arduino

I tried to configure the node on Arduino, but instead, I decided to just configure the controller on the main body and use it.

What advantages does this have?

The advantage of forming a node is that the complexity of the delivery structure is reduced by 1?

What's the downside?
it will be advantage of controller on the main body. But I don`t have any good answer.